# Fill table to available space, fixing the header and footer

Tags: html, css

I have a section which is space-constrained by the size of the viewport (in my live page).

The layout consists of this:

1. Content above table
2. Table > Header + Body
3. Content bellow table

Right now, the section overflows of the table has too many items.
I want it to be scrollable, but I want to fix (1) + header to the top and (3) to the bottom of the space.

Basically, I need the table body to fill the available space, maintaining the content above to the top and the content bellow to the bottom.

How can I do that?

```css
* {
color: #ffffff
}

section 
{
  height: 200px;
}

section .table-wrapper {
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 0;
}

section .row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section .row>* {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}


/* Content above table */
.table-header {
  padding: .75rem .5rem;
}

.table-header .btn-container .add-btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #002088;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: .55rem .75rem;
}

.table-header .btn-container .add-btn span {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}


/* Table */

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

table thead {
  background-color: #605079;
  padding: .5rem;
}

// Table header
table thead tr th {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: .65px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

table thead th {
  border-bottom: 0px transparent;
}

table tbody tr {
  background-color: #505050;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #3b4253;
}

table tbody tr td {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--nav-text);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: .5rem .5rem;
}

table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1),
table thead tr th:nth-of-type(1) {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

select {
  color: #000000;
}

option {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 table-wrapper">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items center table-header">
        <div class="filter-container">
          <label class="mx-2" for="filter">Search</label>
          <input class="mx-2 px-2" type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>

        <div class="btn-container px-2">
          <button type="button" class="add-btn">
            <span>Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <table role="grid">
          <thead>
            <tr role="row">
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Card</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
          <select class="m-2" style="width: auto" name="pageSize">
            <option value="10">10 items per page</option>
            <option value="20">20 items per page</option>
            <option value="30">30 items per page</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

I was able to progress by using a CSS-Grid and setting the correct sizing, separating the three parts into multiple elements (the footer was inside an element along with the table). I just need to fix the table header now.

```css
section .table-wrapper {
  //...
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(100%) auto fit-content(100%);
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
}

section .row {
  //...
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```css
* {
color: #ffffff
}

section 
{
  height: 200px;
}

section .table-wrapper {
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(100%) auto fit-content(100%);
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
}

section .row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

section .row>* {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Content above table */
.table-header {
  padding: .75rem .5rem;
}

.table-header .btn-container .add-btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #002088;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: .55rem .75rem;
}

.table-header .btn-container .add-btn span {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}


/* Table */

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table thead {
  background-color: #605079;
  padding: .5rem;
}

// Table header
table thead tr th {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: .65px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

table thead th {
  border-bottom: 0px transparent;
}

table tbody tr {
  background-color: #505050;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #3b4253;
}

table tbody tr td {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--nav-text);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: .5rem .5rem;
}

table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1),
table thead tr th:nth-of-type(1) {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

select {
  color: #000000;
}

option {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 table-wrapper">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items center table-header">
        <div class="filter-container">
          <label class="mx-2" for="filter">Search</label>
          <input class="mx-2 px-2" type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>

        <div class="btn-container px-2">
          <button type="button" class="add-btn">
            <span>Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="scrollable">
        <table role="grid">
          <thead>
            <tr role="row">
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Card</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>example@example.com</td>
              <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
        <select class="m-2" style="width: auto" name="pageSize">
          <option value="10">10 items per page</option>
          <option value="20">20 items per page</option>
          <option value="30">30 items per page</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So essentially you want to fix your table header on scroll and you want the table to be responsive when setting "Items per page". Please correct me if I am not understanding this correctly.

Comment: I want the table items to fill the available space and be scrollable, with what's before and after to be fixed in place. Like the div before and the header to be fixed to the top and the div after to be fixed to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS and HTML is not enough. You need javascript to achieve your goal.

To be more specific you should use Intersection Observer. Using it you can change css or add/remove class from an element based on its visibility. For example if a user scrolls down to a point the table header is no longer visible you can fire an action. Or when the table header is visible only from 50% or less. You get the idea.

If you have never worked with Intersection Observer, youtube might be good start to understand how it works.

The other option is to calculate everything manually. This way you would need to define how far (how many pixels) a user needs to scroll to fire the action.
The code would looke something like this:

```
if(window.pageYOffset > 150) {
  //do some css change
}
```

[A very basic example of this approach](https://codepen.io/gregorvonvitek/pen/JjXzLvd)